# Unable to use for loop against array data in Yii2

Tags: php, for-loop, yii2

I have a variable `$data` in my controller. In which I am getting the following result

```
Array( [0] => 99 [1] => 100 [2] => 101 [3] => 102 [4] => 103)
```

Now I want to get the single entry one by one by using for loop. The main purpose of this loop is that I want to insert these values in my `DB table`.

```
 if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->post())
    {
        $data = explode(',',$_POST['data']);

       for($i=0; $i<=count($data); $i++)
        {
            print_r($data[$i]);
        }
        //print_r($data);
    }
    else{
        echo 'no data';
    }
    exit();
```

When i Run this one, I am getting the error

> 500 Internal Server Error
>   PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Undefined offset: 5'

**Stack Trace**

```
Stack trace:
#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-
web\backend\controllers\OgpheaderController.php(170): yii\base\ErrorHandler-
&gt;handleError(8, &#039;Undefined offse...&#039;, 
&#039;E:\\xampp\\htdocs...&#039;, 170, Array)
#1 [internal function]: backend\controllers\OgpheaderController-
&gt;actionViewsetpdf(&#039;55&#039;)
#2 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): 
call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(156): yii\base\InlineAction-
&gt;runWithParams(Array)
#4 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523): 
yii\base\Controller-&gt;runAction(&#039;viewsetpdf&#039;, Array)
#5 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(102): yii\base\Module-
&gt;runAction(&#039;ogpheader/views...&#039;, Array)
#6 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(380): yii\web\Application-
&gt;handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#7 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\backend\web\index.php(17): 
yii\base\Application-&gt;run()
#8 {main}</pre>
```

I have searched for this error solution but couldn't find the correct answer(s).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: change to `$i<count($data)`

Comment: the count of data is  5  but the array start for  0 to 4 so ue < count($data)   ..not <=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to

```
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++)
{
  print_r($data[$i]);
}
```

Array has total 5 elements which start with index `0` and end with `4` and when you compare count with `<=` it go to the index `5`.

Answer (score 2):

instead of the for loop, use foreach:

```
foreach($data as $d)
{
    print_r($d);
}
```

makes sure that you always stay within bounds of the array

Answer (score 2):

```
 for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++)
    {
        print_r($data[$i]);
    }
```

or

```
 for($i=0; $i<=count($data)-1; $i++)
    {
        print_r($data[$i]);
    }
```

or

```
foreach($data as $value)
{
print_r($value);
}
```

any of these will work